# What is the difference between mass gained from the Higgs field and relativistic mass gain?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, mass, mass-energy, higgs

I understand the equation for mass gain in special relativity, but what is physically causing the mass increase?  In Higgs theory, mass is said to come from the vacuum potential (VEV). I am assuming this, because the vacuum potential energy is equivalent to mass through $E= mc^2$. Could the mass gain in relativity come from an increase in Higgs VEV potential, or do we just accept what the math in relativity is telling us?

Comment: Faster moving objects have more kinetic energy. By $E=mc^2$ that energy has mass

Comment: @BySymmetry in the appropriate reference frame of course!  Specifically, in its own frame a particle's mass does not increase at all.  Similarly, should we "just accept what the maths in QFT is telling us"?

Answer (score 3):

Mass increase due to velocity close to speed of light is a purely relativistic-kinematical effect related with the fact that the energy of the particle increases with velocity taking correctly (i.e. relativistically) the maximum speed limit, namely speed of light, into account.

However, the Higgs field generates rest mass (considered as constant)   via its non-zero vacuum expectancy value.

Both effects have no relation at all.

Answer (score 3):

In modern physics, we often think of the *invariant mass* (or *rest mass*) of a particle, let's call it $m_0$. Unlike the *relativistic mass* you are referring to in the first part of your question, $m_0$ does *not* depend on the velocity of the particle. It is simply defined to be the mass that the particle has when at rest. It is an intrinsic property of the particle that does not depend on the frame of reference. You can read more about invariant mass here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass

The non-zero background value of the Higgs field leads to a shift in the *invariant mass* of the particles that couple to the Higgs field. This shift in invariant mass is not related to the dependence of relativistic mass on velocity, since the invariant mass does not depend on velocity.

Comment: Does total mass equal invariant mass + relativistic mass for a particle such as an electron moving close to the speed of light  ? Or is it just all relativistic mass at high speeds?

Comment: @Adrdav22 the concept of relativistic mass nowadays is abandoned. There is only total relativistic energy $E=\gamma mc^2$ which at rest -- $\gamma=1$ -- turns out to be $E=mc^2$. Certainly one can split up total energy in rest energy and kinetic energy (called $T$) like $E_{tot} = E_{rest} +T$. And if you like you can associate to each energy mass, nowadays this association is only done for the rest energy respectively rest mass. Obviously $m$ here is the rest mass.

Comment: @Adrdav22 There is a formula linking invariant mass $m_0$, relativistic mass $m_{\rm rel}$, and speed $v$. You can find it, for example, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity. It is
$$
m_{\rm rel} = \gamma m_0
$$
where $\gamma=(1-v^2/c^2)^{-1/2}$ is the famous factor that appears in special relativity.

Comment: @Andrew I know the formula but does it mean we can add small bits of rest mass together because a fast moving electron can have a relativistic mass equal to invariant mass of a stationary proton for example.

Comment: @Adrdav22 What would be the meaning of adding small bits of rest mass together? I don't think I understand.

Comment: Rest mass is a scalar and is invariant, whereas "relativistic mass" is frame dependent.  These comments illustrate just how bad it is to favour frame-dependent (i.e. arbitrary) quantities over invariant scalars.  Even worse to attempt to mix them!

Answer (score 0):

OP and existing posts concerns difference between rest mass (invariant mass) and relativistic mass (which is abandoned). But relativity has more to say about mass: The rest mass of a system is propotional to total energy measured by center-of-momentum (C.O.M) frame (the frame in which system's total momentum is zero).

$$m=\frac{E_\text{C.O.M}}{c^2}.$$

This means even if photon has zero rest mass, a system of photons might has a nonzero rest mass. In case of a hydrogen atom (say only a proton consists nucleus), its rest mass is:

$$m_\text{H}=\frac{1}{c^2}(E^\text{proton}+E^\text{electron}+E^\text{interaction})_\text{C.O.M},$$

where $E^\text{proton}$ and $E^\text{electron}$ consist both kinetic energy due to motion relative to C.O.M frame and rest energy. Further, we could decompose rest mass of proton in the same manner into kinetic and interaction energy of quarks and gluons... As for electron, from what we know its rest mass directly arise from Higgs mechanism, with no contribution from some internal motion & interaction (electron is structureless ).

$$\begin{aligned}
m_\text{H}&=\frac{1}{c^2}(E^\text{proton}+E^\text{electron}+E^\text{interaction})_\text{C.O.M}\\
&=\frac{1}{c^2}(E^\text{proton}+E^\text{electron}_\text{kinetic}+E^\text{electron}_\text{Higgs}+E^\text{interaction})_\text{C.O.M}\\
&=\frac{1}{c^2}(E^\text{proton}_\text{kinetic}+E^\text{proton}_\text{rest}+E^\text{electron}_\text{kinetic}+E^\text{electron}_\text{Higgs}+E^\text{interaction})_\text{C.O.M}\\
&=...
\end{aligned}$$